# In R, is it possible to define a function using `function`?

Tags: r

In R, most statements can be written as a function call. For example...

```
for (ii in 1:10) print(ii)
```

can be written as

```
`for`(ii, 1:10, print(ii))
```

However, when I try to write a function using this approach...

```
# normal approach
function (a = 1) 2

# call approach
`function`(pairlist(a = 1), 2)
```

I get an error: invalid formal argument list for "function". This seems to be referring to the first argument (the pairlist).

Is it possible to define a function directly in this way, without wrapping it in substitute?

A bit of searching turned up this [email thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Creating-functions-programmatically-td4644875.html), which suggests 4 approaches, but none call "`function`" directly.

Comment: Apologies, I overlooked this excellent question when asking my own, and only found it afterwards. I would have closed mine as a duplicate of this one rather than the other way round, but the Stack Overflow software wouldn’t let me.

Comment: No worries--just glad to see some good discussion of the issue the question you posted!