# How do I call the `function` function?

Tags: r

I am trying to call the function `` `function` `` to define a function in R code.

As we all know™️, `` `function` ``is a `.Primitive` that’s used *internally* by R to define functions when the user uses the conventional syntax, i.e.

```
mean1 = function (x, ...) base::mean(x, ...)
```

But there’s nothing preventing me from calling that primitive directly. *Or so I thought*. I can call other primitives directly (and even redefine them; for instance, in a moment of madness [I overrode R’s builtin `` `for` ``](https://gist.github.com/klmr/d10623a0b4c7e1e9a6523eebee4913d1)). So this *is* in principle possible.

Yet I cannot get it to work for `` `function` ``. Here’s what I tried:

```
# Works
mean2 = as.function(c(formals(mean), quote(mean(x, ...))))

# Works
mean3 = eval(call('function', formals(mean), quote(mean(x, ...))))

# Error: invalid formal argument list for "function"
mean4 = `function`(formals(mean), quote(mean(x, ...)))
```

The fact that `mean3` in particular works indicates to me that `mean4` *should* work. But it doesn’t. Why?

I checked the definition of the `` `function` `` primitive in the R source. [`do_function` is defined in `eval.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/780021752eb83a71e2198019acf069ba8741103b/src/main/eval.c#L1563-L1577). And I see that it calls [`CheckFormals`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/780021752eb83a71e2198019acf069ba8741103b/src/main/eval.c#L2101-L2111), which ensures that each argument is a symbol, and this fails. But why does it check this, and what does that mean?

And most importantly: Is there a way of calling the `` `function` `` primitive directly?

---

Just to clarify: There are trivial workarounds (this question lists two, and there’s at least a third). But I’d like to understand how this (does not) works.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53218422/1968 (I swear I found this afterwards)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982528/how-to-create-an-r-function-programmatically

Comment: @Moody's answer in the link above points out [rlang::new_function](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/new_function.html), which _can_ be called directly as a function and does essentially what `function` does.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov … sure but that does exactly what my `mean3` definition does. [I’m well aware of workarounds](https://github.com/klmr/functional/blob/c059576ae44e002277f0c9a0a49352080408e54e/__init__.r#L1-L19), I was just curious why it doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Please see my answer below.

Comment: You probably thought of: `newmean <- do.call( 'function', list(formals(mean), quote(mean(x, ...))))`. Backticks also succeed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because `function` is a special primitive:

```
typeof(`function`)
#> [1] "special"
```

The arguments are not evaluated, so you have actually passed `quote(formals(mean))` instead of the value of `formals(mean)`. I don't think there's a way of calling `function` directly without evaluation tricks, except with an empty formals list which is just `NULL`.

Comment: I actually tried quoting the formals (as well as using `alist`), yet as you noticed this also doesn’t work. ``typeof(`for`)`` is also “special”, but calling ` ``for`` ` manually works.

Comment: Yeah because `for` takes a symbol and two expressions, for which there is parser syntax. There is no explicit parser syntax for creating a pairlist literal, which is what `function()` takes.

Comment: Indeed. I just figured out that you *can* call it with a manually generated `pairlist` — but once again only indirectly because, as you said, there’s no `pairlist` literal syntax.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness’ sake, Lionel’s answer hints at a way of calling `` `function` `` after all. Unfortunately it’s rather restricted, since we cannot pass any argument definition except for `NULL`:

```
mean5 = `function`(NULL, mean(x, ...))
formals(mean5) = formals(mean)
```

(Note the lack of quoting around the body!)

This is of course utterly unpractical (and `formals<-` internally calls `as.function` anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

After digging a little bit through the source code, here are a few observations:

1. The actual function creation is done by [mkCLOSXP()](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/780021752eb83a71e2198019acf069ba8741103b/src/main/dstruct.c#L78). This is what gets called by `function() {}`, by `as.function.default()` and by `.Primitive("function")` (a.k.a. `` `function` ``)
2. `as.function.default()` gets routed to [do_asfunction()](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/780021752eb83a71e2198019acf069ba8741103b/src/main/coerce.c#L1521), which [also calls CheckFormals()](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/780021752eb83a71e2198019acf069ba8741103b/src/main/coerce.c#L1555). However, it directly constructs these formals a few lines above that.
3. As you pointed out, the other place where `CheckFormals()` gets called is inside `do_function()`. However, I don't think `do_function()` gets called by anything *other than* `.Primitive("function")`, so this is the only situation where `CheckFormals()` is called on the user's input.
4. `CheckFormals()` does actually correctly validate a `pairlist` object.

You can check the last point yourself by running parts of the `CheckFormals()` function using `inline::cfunction`

```
inline::cfunction( c(x="ANY"),
  'Rprintf("is list?: %d\\nTag1 OK?: %d\\nTag2 OK?: %d\\nTag3 NULL?: %d\\n",
     isList(x), TYPEOF(TAG(x)) == SYMSXP, TYPEOF(TAG(CDR(x))) == SYMSXP,
     CDR(CDR(x)) == R_NilValue); return R_NilValue;' )( formals(mean) )

# is list?: 1
# Tag1 OK?: 1
# Tag2 OK?: 1
# Tag3 NULL?: 1
```

So, somewhere between you passing `formals(means)` to `.Primitive("function")` and it getting forwarded to `CheckFormals()` by `do_function()`, the argument loses its validity. (I don't know the R source well enough to tell you how that happens.) However, since `do_function()` is only called by `.Primitive("function")`, you don't encounter this situation with any other examples.

Comment: You’re spot on as far as your reasoning goes. I think the missing piece to the puzzle is the declaration of `function` in `names.c`: Unlike your own C function, `do_function` doesn’t get called with the evaluated argument; instead, it gets called with *unevaluated* arguments, so what gets passed isn’t a pairlist, it’s a quoted expression that would evaluate to a pairlist.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Do you think this is intended behavior? Neither `do_function`, nor `\`function\``, nor `.Primitive("function")` get used internally (as determined by `grep`-ing the source). So, if a user can't call it directly, who is the function meant for?

Comment: The function `.Primitive("function")` is called when you evaluate a call to `function` created by the parser into a function object created by the interpreter. Note that those two kinds of objects print identically, which can be confusing. Check the differences between `quote(function(foo, bar) NULL)` and the unquoted version. You can also verify with `.Internal(inspect(quote(function(foo, bar) NULL)))` that the parser correctly creates the formals list in calls to `function`.